# Wordpress/woocommerce redirect after registration

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom registration page on my Woocommerce site created by a developer who has gone awol.

Once you have registered on the website it redirects you to:
http://www.punjaban.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=load_lightbox&lightboxTemplate=register

which is wrong and only displays the my-account page but with no formatting.

I tried adding:

```
function punjaban_registration_redirect() {
    return home_url;
}

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'punjaban_registration_redirect' );
```

but that has not worked. Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

The custom register.php code is:

```
    <?php global $myaccount_page_url; ?>

<h1><?php _e( 'Create an account', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h1>

<form method="post" class="register account-form" action="<?php echo $myaccount_page_url; ?>?action=register">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>
    <div class="row">


        <div class="column xsmall-12 small-6">
            <input type="text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'FIRST NAME', 'punjaban' ); ?>" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="column xsmall-12 small-6">
            <input type="text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'LAST NAME', 'punjaban' ); ?>" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
        </div>

        <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

                <div class="column xsmall-12">
                    <label for="reg_username"><?php _e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'USERNAME', 'punjaban' ); ?>" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ); ?>" />
                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="column xsmall-12">
                            <label for="reg_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'EMAIL ADDRESS', 'punjaban' ); ?>" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ); ?>" />
            </div>





        <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

        <div class="column xsmall-12">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="reg_password" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'PASSWORD', 'punjaban' ); ?>" />
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <!-- Spam Trap -->
        <div style="left: -999em; position: absolute;"><label for="trap"><?php _e( 'Anti-spam', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="email_2" id="trap" tabindex="-1" /></div>

        <div class="column xsmall-12">
            <input type="password" name="password2" id="reg_password2" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'CONFIRM PASSWORD', 'punjaban' ); ?>" />
        </div>


        <div class="column xsmall-12">
            <div class="custom-checkbox">
                <input name="newsletter" type="checkbox" id="newsletter" value="1" checked="checked" />
                <label for="newsletter"><span class="icon"></span> <?php _e('Keep me posted with new recipes and news','punjaban'); ?></label>
            </div>
        </div>


        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>
        <?php do_action( 'register_form' ); ?>

        <div class="column xsmall-12">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register' ); ?>
            <input type="submit" class="btn form-btn" name="register" value="<?php _e( 'CREATE ACCOUNT', 'punjaban' ); ?>" />
        </div>



    </div>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>
</form>

<div class="login-switch">
    <h2>Already have an account?</h2>
    <a href="<?php echo $myaccount_page_url; ?>" class="btn login-instead"><?php _e( 'LOGIN', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably returning wrong value. 
You should *return homer_url();* function.

--EDIT

Also you could try *"woocommerce_registration_redirect"* filter instead of *"registration_redirect"*

Comment: Thanks pa7ryk, I tried adding a new function with the return home_url() but that did not work, I cannot see where this admin-ajax url is being generated so I cannot see where to change the parameter.

Comment: try to find if there is another hook invoke in your wordpress files by searching this string "registration_redirect"